# how to Chopping string in matlab

Tags: matlab

For example, I have This string

```
x='004000500100'
```

I want to convert every 4 elements of it to a character array.

the result of the string will be :

```
y={'0040','0050','0100'}
```

Comment: Am I correct assuming that `y={[0 0 4 0], [0 0 5 0], [0 1 0 0]}`?

Comment: do you have `x=004000500100` or `x='004000500100'` ?

Comment: I haxe x='004000500100' (that is example string ' ), i would to chopping it into string such as '0040','0050','0100, as you see every 4 element will be one string or one integer

Comment: But `'0040','0050','0100'` is not an integer array?

Comment: but that simple to convert it to integer by num2str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to split a character vector into character vectors of a fixed size.

If the original size **is a multiple** of the target size, you can do it very easily as follows:

```
x = '004000500100';
S = 4;
result = cellstr(reshape(x,4,[]).');
```

If the original size **may not be a multiple** of the target size, a possible approach is:

```
result = accumarray(ceil((1:numel(x))/S).', x(:), [], @(t) {t.'});
```

Comment: Just a quick note. This only works if `x` is a list of chars, if it is a string (as OP technically says) `x = "004000500100";` you will first have to convert it to a list of chars with `char(x)`.